# check_totals wrt a large vector in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I'd like to check the total derivatives of an output with respect to a large array of inputs, but I don't want to check the derivative with respect to every member of the array, since the array is too large, and the complex steps (or finite differences) across each member of the array would take too long.  Is there a way to check_totals wrt just a single member of an array?

Alternatively, is there a way to perform a directional derivative across the entire array for check_totals?  This feature seems to exist for check_partials only?

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 3.1.1 of OpenMDAO we don't have directional checking for totals, but it is a good idea and we are probably going to implement it when we figure out the best way.

As a workaround for now, I think the easiest way to take a directional derivative of your model is to temporarily modify your model by creating a component that takes a "step" in some random direction, and then inserting it in front of your component with wide inputs. I've put together a simple example here:

```
import numpy as np
import openmdao.api as om

n = 50

class DirectionalComp(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', 1.0)
        self.add_output('y', np.ones(n))
        self.A = -1.0 + 2.0 * np.random.random(n)

        self.declare_partials('y', 'x', rows=np.arange(n), cols=np.repeat(0, n), val=self.A)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs, discrete_inputs=None, discrete_outputs=None):
        x = inputs['x']
        outputs['y'] = x * self.A


prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

# Add something like this
model.add_subsystem('p', om.IndepVarComp('x', 1.0))
model.add_subsystem('direction', DirectionalComp())

model.connect('p.x', 'direction.x')
model.connect('direction.y', 'comp.x')

model.add_design_var('p.x')

# Old Model
model.add_subsystem('comp', om.ExecComp('y = 2.0*x', x=np.ones((n, )), y=np.ones((n, ))))

model.add_constraint('comp.y', lower=0.0)

prob.setup()
prob.run_model()
totals = prob.check_totals()
```

Comment: Thanks.  How about the first part of the question, where I'm looking to compute partials wrt a single member of an input array.  Will this also require a specialized component, or can it somehow be done with check_totals as things stand now?

Comment: There isn't a good way to check partials with a single index of an array. You could fake it with check_totals and a model with just the component and the scalar IVC hooked up to the index of choice for now